# How to enable Infinispan smallrye metrics in Wildfly 20?

Tags: wildfly, metrics, infinispan, microprofile, smallrye

We want to expose the metrics of our Hibernate caches into Prometheus, and have for the time being built our own metrics for the caches, but since Infinispan 10 provides native metrics support, we'd rather use that.

So when I curl the localhost:9990/metrics and look for infinispan related metrics, I find nothing. I do find jgroups, and our own metrics.

The configuration for the metrics in the standalone.xml is:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:microprofile-metrics-smallrye:2.0" 
    security-enabled="false" 
    exposed-subsystems="*" 
    prefix="${wildfly.metrics.prefix:wildfly}"
/>
```

We've also added "statistics-enabled=true" to the defined infinispan cache-containers:

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" 
    default-cache="local-query" 
    module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache" 
    statistics-enabled="true">
```

I've searched the web for Infinispan, Wildfly, metrics, but I only find generic metrics articles about how you can create your own, or the announcements of added support for metrics in Infinispan.

According to the subsystem configuration all metrics should be exposed. Is there anything that we need to configure in addition to enable infinispan metrics inside wildfly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found out that there is a bug in Wildfly 20, so that infinispan statistics aren't exported. See [WFLY-14063](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14063) and the fixing [pull-request](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/13707).

The fix version mentioned in the ticket is 22.0.0.Beta1.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it is going to work, there is a `metrics` tag in `cache-container` that needs to be configured/enabled:

```
<cache-container statistics="true"> 
    <metrics gauges="true" histograms="true" /> 
</cache-container>
```

See the infinispan [configuration doc](https://infinispan.org/docs/10.1.x/titles/configuring/configuring.html#configure_metrics)

Comment: Yes, I found that in the infinispan documentation, but that is not the actual configuration that Wildfly uses, as they use the subsystem for infinispan configuration, which is different (and more limited). 

Using the `<metrics />` element in standalone.xml causes Wildfly not to start with a parsing error.